# Add an easing function to a PointAnimationUsingPath

Tags: wpf, animation, easing-functions

How could I add an easing function to my PointAnimationUsingPath?

It hasn't a `EasingFunction` property like the `DoubleAnimation` has.

Here's my animation:

```
<PointAnimationUsingPath
        Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedEllipseGeometry"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Center"
        Duration="0:0:.8" 
        RepeatBehavior="Forever">

    <PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>

        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure>
                <BezierSegment Point1="0 0" Point2="200 -300" Point3="400 0"/>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>

    </PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>

</PointAnimationUsingPath>
```

I'd like to add this easing function:

```
<CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
```

Is there a way to do it, or should I use an other method? I precise that I want to use a Bezier curve as path for the animation.

Comment: There is no easing function, but you might use AccelerationRatio and DecelerationRatio.

Comment: Didn't see those properties! Thanks :)